# Format Numbers in Multiple columns of SSRS Report

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2012, ssrs-2008

Currently I am working on a ssrs report. The table in report is having about 30 columns. For each column I have to modify the number format (to either 2 decimal or no decimal numbers). I can do it by click on every column and modify the number property in format menu. But is there any way to format all the columns at a time?

I tried to select entire row -> F4 -> properties -> Number -> Format-> Expression. And set expression to:

`=FormatNumber(Fields!HoursWorked.Value&Fields!ContactAttempted.Value&Fields!UnableToContact.Value,2)`

But it throws an error

> Type character '&' does not match declared data type 'Object'.

Can any one help me on this?

Comment: When does the error appear? Does it work if you do the same steps and select 1 column?

Comment: it works when i selected one column. error appears when i try to preview the report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really, really stupid; you have to have spaces before and after the ampersand, and if you don't then you tend to get that error message. I don't know why, it's daft as hell but I bet that's it. Catches me out constantly. Try:

```
=FormatNumber(Fields!HoursWorked.Value & Fields!ContactAttempted.Value & Fields!UnableToContact.Value,2)
```

Comment: It's fairly common for programming languages to require spaces between references, even when it isn't in my view you should do this anyway for readability.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the `Format` property of a cell (or cells - note you CAN set the format for multiple cells at the same time) then you need to specify a value or expression that resolves to a recognised format string, e.g. `'$'0,.00;'$'-0,.00` or `C2`.

The expression you have given returns the actual formatted **value** of the cell, so this will not work if entered into the `Format` property - this needs to go in the `Value` property of the textbox.

Answer (score -1):

You need to set format number for each column separately. If you don't want to set number format in `Text Box Properties`, you can set format such way:

Click on cell with value -> F4 -> field `Format` in `Properties` -> set format (for example, you can use this format: `#,0.00` for numbers with space as 1000 separator and negative numbers as `-12 345.00`)